# Question Regarding Django's South and the Migration of Data

Tags: django, django-south

I'm just starting with South and one question that I have is not answered in what I have read so far.

Here is the thing: what about the data? Does South makes a dump of all data into a fixture, changes the schema and than reloads all of it? In the case of my model's change be the deletion of a column, does South parse the data removing it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Why would it do that? It simply runs ALTER TABLE statements on the database.